# How to change request URI in ExtJS 4.1.0 Proxy or Reader

Tags: javascript, rest, extjs, extjs4, uri

As it is, ExtJS 4.1 with a Rest proxy and a Json reader asks for a URI like this (urlencoded, though):

`http://localhost:8000/api/v1/choice/?filter=[{"property":"question_id","value":2}]`

my server wants filter requests to look like:

`http://localhost:8000/api/v1/choice/?question_id=2`

I've looked at the `filterParam` config for the proxy, but it doesn't seem relevant. Is there a practical way to achieve the request URI that the server needs?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Following ain't pretty, but it works. Now to fix the damn Store...

```
/**
         * Customized to send ../?prop=val&prop2=val2 urls.
         */
        buildUrl: function(request) {
            var url = this.url;
            var filters = eval(request.params['filter']);
            if (filters) {
                delete request.params['filter'];
                url += '?'
                for (var i = 0; i < filters.length; i++) {
                    var filterString = filters[i].property + "=" + filters[i].value;
                    if (url.slice(url.length-1) === '?') {
                        url += filterString;
                    } else {
                        url += '&' + filterstring;
                    } 
                }
            };
            return url;
        },
```

Answer (score 1):

There is no simple (easy) way. You will have to extend existing `Proxy` class. Take a look at the source code for `Ext.data.proxy.Proxy` and `Ext.data.proxy.Server`. Start with looking at functions `getParams` and `buildUrl`

Comment: Thanks. I'm looking at `buildUrl` now. If I get something working, I'll post it to wrap this up.